# Python reorder a sorted list so the highest value is in the middle

Tags: python, sorting, partitioning

I need to reorder a sorted list so the "middle" element is the highest number. The numbers leading up to the middle are incremental, the numbers past the middle are in decreasing order.

I have the following working solution, but have a feeling that it can be done simpler:

```
foo = range(7)
bar = [n for i, n in enumerate(foo) if n % 2 == len(foo) % 2]
bar += [n for n in reversed(foo) if n not in bar]
bar
[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: The list will be displayed horizontal (and won't contain numbers). Visually it makes sense to put the "highest" number in the middle and descent outwards form there...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

how about:

```
foo[len(foo)%2::2] + foo[::-2]

In [1]: foo = range(7)
In [2]: foo[len(foo)%2::2] + foo[::-2]
Out[2]: [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 0]
In [3]: foo = range(8)
In [4]: foo[len(foo)%2::2] + foo[::-2]
Out[4]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: That's pretty cool and works perfectly for my use case. I always forget about the extended slice syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing with a step of 2 going up, and -2 going back:

```
>>> foo[1::2]+foo[-1::-2]
[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Comment: It's worth noting the list needs to be sorted first. So `foo.sort()` then this, if you don't know it's sorted.